# How to addition of multiple hour in php in HH:MM format

Tags: php

I have following array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 25:50
    [1] => 21:00
    [2] => 42:40
)
```

I m trying to add hours in php, i have tried following code. But it get me wrong time calculation.

```
$time_cal = 0;
foreach ($time as $time_cal) {
    $time_cal += strtotime($time_cal);
}
echo date('H:i', strtotime($time_cal));
```

Reason behind this strtotime function is give only under 24 hour time calculation which is right but when i tried above 24 hour like 25:55, 44:44 that give me wrong calculation.

Any Idea ?

Comment: I'm not sure to have exactly understood the question. You have an array ($time) and you want to sum up its elements?

Comment: there is  $time array,it is in hh:mm , and need to get all addition of hour and minute

Comment: Ok, just give me some minutes to build an answer.

Comment: Since these strings are elapsed time, why not  just parse the hours out and add them up. Parse the minutes and add up. Modulo 60 on the minutes to get exact minutes. Divide by 60 to get additional hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code may be help full to you.. i have created two function 
1) explode_time
2) second_to_hhmm

```
function explode_time($time) { //explode time and convert into seconds
        $time = explode(':', $time);
        $time = $time[0] * 3600 + $time[1] * 60;
        return $time;
}

function second_to_hhmm($time) { //convert seconds to hh:mm
        $hour = floor($time / 3600);
        $minute = strval(floor(($time % 3600) / 60));
        if ($minute == 0) {
            $minute = "00";
        } else {
            $minute = $minute;
        }
        $time = $hour . ":" . $minute;
        return $time;
}

$time = 0;
$time_arr =  array("23:59","01:01","2:50");
 foreach ($time_arr as $time_val) {
    $time +=explode_time($time_val); // this fucntion will convert all hh:mm to seconds
}

echo second_to_hhmm($time); // this function will  convert all seconds to HH:MM.
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this.

```
$remove_mins = date('H', strtotime( $time_to_add));
$time_cal = 0;
foreach ($time as $time_cal) {
    $time_cal = date('H:i', strtotime("+" . $remove_mins . " hour",strtotime( $time_cal)));
}
echo date('H:i', strtotime($time_cal));
```

when there is more than 24 hours, the +hour function does not work if you try to add minutes, so you just need to get the amount of hours without the amount of minutes

Answer (score 1):

```
function AddTimeToStr($aElapsedTimes) {
  $totalHours = 0;
  $totalMinutes = 0;

  foreach($aElapsedTimes as $time) {
    $timeParts = explode(":", $time);
    $h = $timeParts[0];
    $m = $timeParts[1];
    $totalHours += $h;
    $totalMinutes += $m;
  }

  $additionalHours = floor($totalMinutes / 60);
  $minutes = $totalMinutes % 60;
  $hours = $totalHours + $additionalHours;

  $strMinutes = strval($minutes);
  if ($minutes < 10) {
      $strMinutes = "0" . $minutes;
  }

  $strHours = strval($hours);
  if ($hours < 10) {
      $strHours = "0" . $hours;
  }

  return($strHours . ":" . $strMinutes);
}

// your sample
echo AddTimeToStr(array("25:50", "21:00", "42:40")) . "<br/>";

// more flexibility. Lets you specify more than 99 hours
echo AddTimeToStr(array("100:50", "00:05", "22:40")) . "<br/>";

// check before, at, after hour boundaries
echo AddTimeToStr(array("00:50", "00:09")) . "<br/>";
echo AddTimeToStr(array("00:50", "00:10")) . "<br/>";
echo AddTimeToStr(array("00:50", "00:11")) . "<br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the hours:

```
substr($time_cal,0,2);
```

To get the minutes:

```
substr($time_cal,3,2);
```

Then convert to numbers as it is a string

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime` object to make operations with dates

```
$dates = array("21:00", "01:05", "03:00");
$sum = new DateTime("00:00");

foreach($dates as $date)
{
    $elements = explode(':',$date);
    $hours = (string)((int)$elements[0]);
    $minutes = (string)((int)$elements[1]);

    $dv = new DateInterval('PT'.$hours.'H'.$minutes.'M');
    $sum->add($dv);
}

echo $sum->format('H:i');
```

This will output `01:05` because it automatically makes modulo on hours.