# Adding 3 time values using PHP

Tags: php

I have three time values (Echoed from mysql database)

```
$time  = 01:58:00;
$time2 = 01:10:00;
$time3  = 02:08:00;
```

I have tried various options.

Below code works with 2 time values, but never reached the solution to add 3 or more time values.

```
$secs = strtotime($time2)-strtotime("00:00:00");
$result = date("H:i:s",strtotime($time)+$secs);
```

Anyone here got any solution..

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: what is desired output?

Comment: Have to echo $result as 5:16:00

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124074/how-to-addition-of-multiple-hour-in-php-in-hhmm-format

Comment: @Chetan .. Thanks for the link..

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime::add](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) here. Try this:

```
$time  = '01:58:00';
$customTime = new DateTime($time);
$customTime->add(new DateInterval('PT1H10M')); // Add 01:10:00
$customTime->add(new DateInterval('PT2H8M'));  // Add 02:08:00

echo $customTime->format('H:i:s') . "\n"; // 05:16:00
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting these values from the database which changes randomly.. How can I make your solution work!!